# Stealing one or one Hundred 

Tags: halacha, money, hashkafah-philosophy, sin

I wanted to Know any **SOURCES** and their answers as to if I steal 1 dollar or one hundred dollars is it the same Sin or is it different? Is it one sin of stealing or one Hundred? When you are punished is it the same for the Hundred dollar theif and the one dollar theif?

Comment: It may be one lav either way, but it causes more harm to another person to steal more from him, so its obviously a worse sin.

Comment: @Ariel K Stealing 1 dollar from a beggar is more harm than stealing 100 dollars from a Billionaire.

Answer (score 7):

It would seem to be one single sin of stealing in either case. A possible proof is from Rambam, Hil. Geneivah 3:14, discussing the cases in which a person is or isn't sold as a Jewish slave in payment of his theft. The Rambam writes (translation from [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088870/jewish/Chapter-Three.htm)):

> When the principal of a theft was
>   worth 100 zuz and the thief could be
>   sold for only 50 zuz, he shall be
>   sold, and the remainder of the
>   principal and the double payment is
>   considered a debt incumbent on him
>   until he attains his freedom in the
>   seventh year, acquires the resources
>   and pays.
>
> If the thief was worth 101 zuz, he
>   shall not be sold. This is derived
>   from the above verse, which states:
>   "He shall be sold for his theft."
>   Implied is that his entire worth must
>   be included in the money received for
>   his theft.

Now, if the theft of 100 zuz was really 100 separate thefts of one zuz each, then the two cases would be exactly similar: in both of them he's worth more than what he stole. The fact that halachah says he should be sold in the first case indicates that it's considered one unitary theft.